# How to set a marker on SupportMapFragment in tabbed Activity?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-markers

I try to implement support map fragment inside of a fragment in tabbed activity.

I try to set a map, and set markers on the map. I succeed to set the map, but not the marker. I tried to find an answer, but I couldn't fix the problem by myself. I would love some help.

The map fragment code:

```
 public class Map_frag extends SupportMapFragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener {

     private SharedPreferences sp;
     private Context context;
     private float myLat, myLng, locLat, locLnf;
     public GoogleMap map;
     private Marker marker;
     // Empty  constructor
     public Map_frag() {}

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container,false);
        context = getContext();
        sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

        return v;
   }
   @Override
   public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();

   }

   private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {

        if (map == null) {
            getMapAsync(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {

        this.map = map;
        onLocChange();
    }

    public void onLocChange(){
        if (map ==null) {
            map.clear();
            if (marker !=null){
                marker.remove();
            }
            myLat = Float.parseFloat(sp.getString("lat", "0"));
            myLng = Float.parseFloat(sp.getString("lng", "0"));
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(myLat, myLng);
            marker = map.addMarker( new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("myLoc"));

            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.
            newLatLngZoom(latLng,15));

        }
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    }
}
```

And the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#00d05b5b">

            <fragment android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
              android:id="@+id/fragment2"
              android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
              tools:layout="@layout/place_autocomplete_fragment"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you only try to set markers  when map is null

Comment: what is `onLocChange` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onLocChange`  what is this? `onLocationChanged` is an override method.You can use it.

**Note:** you have created your own `onLocChange` method and you call it on `onMapReady` so it gets only called at the *First* time. Then `onLocChange` does not get called. but if you have used  `onLocationChanged` override method it gets called every time when the location changes!!

inside that

remove you first if block it covers all the code and only works when the map is null , when map is null there is no point of adding a marker, keep it away..  or use it like below

```
   if(map==null){
    //map null
    } else {
    // add code for markers 
    }
```

If you use above block this should go with else part

```
 if (currLocationMarker != null) {
// you already have a marker so when location changes you remove it and add a new one thats why you need this 
                currLocationMarker.remove();
            }

 latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions(); // just added to clear thingsyou you can add this where instance creates only once 
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(iconForVehicleMarker);

        currLocationMarker = mGoogleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
```

want a full example with everything you need to know([additional](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-java))? see how `onMapReady` `onLocationChaged` and relevant methods used here

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihood;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceLikelihoodBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

/**
 * An activity that displays a map showing places around the device's current location.
 */
public class MapsActivityCurrentPlaces extends AppCompatActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = MapsActivityCurrentPlaces.class.getSimpleName();
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private CameraPosition mCameraPosition;

    // The entry point to Google Play services, used by the Places API and Fused Location Provider.
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    // A request object to store parameters for requests to the FusedLocationProviderApi.
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    // The desired interval for location updates. Inexact. Updates may be more or less frequent.
    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 10000;
    // The fastest rate for active location updates. Exact. Updates will never be more frequent
    // than this value.
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS =
            UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;

    // A default location (Sydney, Australia) and default zoom to use when location permission is
    // not granted.
    private final LatLng mDefaultLocation = new LatLng(-33.8523341, 151.2106085);
    private static final int DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15;
    private static final int PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION = 1;
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted;

    // The geographical location where the device is currently located.
    private Location mCurrentLocation;

    // Keys for storing activity state.
    private static final String KEY_CAMERA_POSITION = "camera_position";
    private static final String KEY_LOCATION = "location";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
            mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
        }

        // Retrieve the content view that renders the map.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Build the Play services client for use by the Fused Location Provider and the Places API.
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Get the device location and nearby places when the activity is restored after a pause.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            getDeviceLocation();
        }
        updateMarkers();
    }

    /**
     * Stop location updates when the activity is no longer in focus, to reduce battery consumption.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Saves the state of the map when the activity is paused.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        if (mMap != null) {
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION, mMap.getCameraPosition());
            outState.putParcelable(KEY_LOCATION, mCurrentLocation);
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Gets the device's current location and builds the map
     * when the Google Play services client is successfully connected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        getDeviceLocation();
        // Build the map.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    /**
     * Handles failure to connect to the Google Play services client.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult result) {
        // Refer to the reference doc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might
        // be returned in onConnectionFailed.
        Log.d(TAG, "Play services connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    /**
     * Handles suspension of the connection to the Google Play services client.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Play services connection suspended");
    }

    /**
     * Handles the callback when location changes.
     */
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mCurrentLocation = location;
        updateMarkers();
    }

    /**
     * Manipulates the map when it's available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        mMap = map;

        // Turn on the My Location layer and the related control on the map.
        updateLocationUI();
        // Add markers for nearby places.
        updateMarkers();

        // Use a custom info window adapter to handle multiple lines of text in the
        // info window contents.
        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            // Return null here, so that getInfoContents() is called next.
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
                // Inflate the layouts for the info window, title and snippet.
                View infoWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_contents, null);

                TextView title = ((TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.title));
                title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView snippet = ((TextView) infoWindow.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
                snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                return infoWindow;
            }
        });
        /*
         * Set the map's camera position to the current location of the device.
         * If the previous state was saved, set the position to the saved state.
         * If the current location is unknown, use a default position and zoom value.
         */
        if (mCameraPosition != null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition));
        } else if (mCurrentLocation != null) {
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(),
                            mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current location is null. Using defaults.");
            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mDefaultLocation, DEFAULT_ZOOM));
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient.
     * Uses the addApi() method to request the Google Places API and the Fused Location Provider.
     */
    private synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                        this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .build();
        createLocationRequest();
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the location request.
     */
    private void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        /*
         * Sets the desired interval for active location updates. This interval is
         * inexact. You may not receive updates at all if no location sources are available, or
         * you may receive them slower than requested. You may also receive updates faster than
         * requested if other applications are requesting location at a faster interval.
         */
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        /*
         * Sets the fastest rate for active location updates. This interval is exact, and your
         * application will never receive updates faster than this value.
         */
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the current location of the device and starts the location update notifications.
     */
    private void getDeviceLocation() {
        /*
         * Request location permission, so that we can get the location of the
         * device. The result of the permission request is handled by a callback,
         * onRequestPermissionsResult.
         */
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.getApplicationContext(),
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        }
        /*
         * Get the best and most recent location of the device, which may be null in rare
         * cases when a location is not available.
         * Also request regular updates about the device location.
         */
        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mCurrentLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,
                    mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the result of the request for location permissions.
     */
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           @NonNull String permissions[],
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    mLocationPermissionGranted = true;
                }
            }
        }
        updateLocationUI();
    }

    /**
     * Adds markers for places nearby the device and turns the My Location feature on or off,
     * provided location permission has been granted.
     */
    private void updateMarkers() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            // Get the businesses and other points of interest located
            // nearest to the device's current location.
            @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
            PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi
                    .getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {
                    for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                        // Add a marker for each place near the device's current location, with an
                        // info window showing place information.
                        String attributions = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAttributions();
                        String snippet = (String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getAddress();
                        if (attributions != null) {
                            snippet = snippet + "\n" + attributions;
                        }

                        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(placeLikelihood.getPlace().getLatLng())
                                .title((String) placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName())
                                .snippet(snippet));
                    }
                    // Release the place likelihood buffer.
                    likelyPlaces.release();
                }
            });
        } else {
            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(mDefaultLocation)
                    .title(getString(R.string.default_info_title))
                    .snippet(getString(R.string.default_info_snippet)));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Updates the map's UI settings based on whether the user has granted location permission.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    private void updateLocationUI() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
            mCurrentLocation = null;
        }
    }
}
```